# How to find index of maximum value of a 2D tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I have three questions:

1. Is there any way to extract maximum values and its indices from a 2D tensor?

Suppose we have a tensor `x = tf.constant([[0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 8], [2, 9, 0]])`, the desired output would be `max = 9, index = [2,1]`.

I've tried the function  `tf.argmax`, however the argument `axis` of `tf.argmax` doesn't accept `tuple` type, for exmple: it doesn't works when `axis = (0, 1)`, only when `axis = 0` or `axis = 1`.

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987509/tensorflow-max-of-a-tensor-along-an-axis) question but they did not answer my question above.

2. Also, how can I find a number of the maximum value (let's say the first 5 maximum value) of a 2D tensor, since `tf.reduce_max` only returns 1?
3. And after having the indices, how can I use these indices to index the value from another tensor `y` that has the same size of `x` above?

**Update 1**: As Aldream pointed out that the first two of my question is a duplicate of this question [How to find the top k values in a 2-D tensor in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797807/how-to-find-the-top-k-values-in-a-2-d-tensor-in-tensorflow). Still, the third question remains.

**Update 2**: For the third question, if anyone has the same problem, we can use `tf.gather`.